# Importing "outside" java class in embedeed OSGi equinox framework

Tags: osgi, equinox

I have to embed Eclipse/Equinox OSGi Framework to existing application.

I found this tutorial http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html and try to use FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA Constans.

So I try export a simple java class into running framework by system bundle, but I receive following error from my activator bundle

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.bundleactivator.Activator for bundle com.bundleactivator is invalid
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:751)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:276)
at RunNewEquinoxOsgi.main(RunNewEquinoxOsgi.java:74)
    Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The import example cannot be resolved

at com.bundleactivator.Activator.<init>(Activator.java:8)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:151)
... 5 more
```

Exceptions are thrown in the place where I import the example.osgi package from system bundle in the activator

```
    import example.osgi.Example;
```

I launch equinox by FrameworkFactory in other java class

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.ServiceLoader;
    import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
    import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
    import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
    import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
    import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;
    import example.osgi.*;

    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,
    "example.osgi;version=\"1.0.0\"");
    try {
        framework.start();
        System.out.println("Framework start");
    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BundleContext ctx = framework.getBundleContext();

    Bundle b3 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\ds.jar");
    System.out.println(b3.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b4 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\services.jar");
    System.out.println(b4.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b5 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\util.jar");
    System.out.println(b5.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b6 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\service.jar");
    System.out.println(b6.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b7 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\rule1.jar");
    System.out.println(b7.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b8 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\rule2.jar");
    System.out.println(b8.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b9 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\rule3.jar");
    System.out.println(b9.getBundleId() + " installed");
    Bundle b10 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\equinoxtest\\activator.jar");
    System.out.println(b10.getBundleId() + " installed");

    b3.start();
    b4.start();
    b5.start();
    b6.start();
    b7.start();
    b8.start();
    b9.start();
    b10.start(); // here i start the activator
```

This is the manifest of activator class

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: BundleActivator
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.bundleactivator
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
    Bundle-Activator: com.bundleactivator.Activator
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
    Import-Package: com.bundleservice,
     example.osgi;version="1.0.0";resolution:=optional,
     org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
     org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.0"
    Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
    Export-Package: com.bundleactivator
```

In the OSGi console i see this package (example.osgi) in system bundle exports, but the importing class(activator) throw Exception. What else should i do?

```
    >osgi packages 0
    ...
    example.osgi; version="1.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210 [0]>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
 java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem
```

indicates that you are building your code with Eclipse, but there are compilation errors. You need to make your code compile before you run it.

Background info: Eclipse does not use the `javac` command for compilation, it has a built-in Java compiler known as ECJ. This compiler is designed for incremental use inside the IDE, and it tries its best to keep going even in the presence of errors. So it will still produce a valid .class file, however if you actually try to run something that touches the class(es) with errors in, then you get the above runtime error. In contrast, `javac` simply stops when it hits a compilation error and will not produce a .class file that you can run.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Your answer indicate another question. So how can I use classes from "other" application in the osgi bundles which I try to run from the FrameworkFactory? I thought it is imported while application is running and using of System Packages Extra and import class from it is enough. How to make those "extra" classes visible before compiling and run it error free?

Comment: My blog post that you linked to tells you only how to do this in runtime. It seems that you're asking about how to do this at build time, but I can't answer that because you haven't said anything about your build environment. E.g. are you setting up a "plain Java" project in Eclipse, or PDE, or using [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/)? Are you building with Maven, ANT or something else?

Comment: I used Eclipse Plug-in Development to create bundles(activator, service interface, service implementation). Launcher of the framework and "extra class" which I try to export by system_packages_extra are the (plain) Java Projects also in Eclipse of course. When I run it without "extra class" it works fine(I'm using declarative services). I created bundles(.jar) in Eclipse by Export -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments. I import the "extra class" package to the launcher class it is the right way?

Comment: Hopefully somebody who knows PDE will help you, I haven't used it for years. If you're serious about OSGi development you probably want to ditch PDE as quickly as possible and use Bndtools...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to solve my issue with Bndtools. I hope it will works.