# Using regular java class in OSGi bundles

Tags: java, class, osgi, bundle

I have to update my question from this thread
[Importing "outside" java class in embedeed OSGi equinox framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869412/importing-outside-java-class-in-embedeed-osgi-equinox-framework). 
It is possible to import regular java package (not bundle) without manifest file by System bundle (or any other way) and use it in installed bundles?

Comment: OSGi uses "regular" Java classes and packages. There's no other kind. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a class from a normal jar in OSGi. You simply add the class to the classpath of the starter of the framework and add the packages you need to the 
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra property.

The system bundle is responsible for exporting classes from the non OSGi classpath into the OSGi system.

This way is a bit inconsistent with normal bundle deployment though. So a better way may be to use the bnd tool or the maven bundle plugin to convert your non OSGi jar into a regular bundle.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi does use "regular Java classes"; the difference is in the jar manifests, which turn them into bundles. Any jar you want to include in your OSGi installation has to have a bundle manifest listing its dependencies and what it provides.